# looking for file in repo with certain properties

Tags: github, github-api

In GitHub, is it possible to search for repos with greater than 100 stars, and contains a file called "`foo.txt`"?

I am trying to use their search interface.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly, [considering the GitHub search limitation](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-code/#considerations-for-code-search) (or "Considerations").

> - Only the default branch is considered. In most cases, this will be the `master` branch.
> - Only files smaller than 384 KB are searchable.
> - Only repositories with fewer than 500,000 files are searchable.
> - **You must always include at least one search term when searching source code**.
>     For example, searching for `language:go` is not valid, while `amazing language:go` is.